# Draw path from split node part

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I would like to draw something like the following:

```
+-------+
| Alpha |
+-------+      +---------+
| betas |----->| Beta    |
+-------+      +---------+      +--------+
| foo   |      | gammas  |----->| Gamma  |
+-------+      +---------+      +--------+
| bar   |      | foo     |      | deltas |
+-------+      +---------+      +--------+
               | bar     |      | foo    |
               +---------+      +--------+
                                | bar    |
                                +--------+
```

Actually, it keeps going until `Epsilon`.

I have the following so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    mod/.style={%
        draw,%
        rectangle split,rectangle split parts=4,%
        minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2cm}%
]
    \node[mod] (a) {%
        Alpha
        \nodepart{two} betas
        \nodepart{three} foo
        \nodepart{four} bar
    };
    \node[mod,right=of a] (b) {%
        Beta
        \nodepart{two} gammas
        \nodepart{three} foo
        \nodepart{four} bar
    };
    \node[mod,right=of b] (c) {%
        Gamma
        \nodepart{two} deltas
        \nodepart{three} foo
        \nodepart{four} bar
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: output of MWE]

**How could I draw a path from the `betas` split node part for example? I mean how do I specify that coordinate?**

I suppose knowing the answer to the above question would also solve the problem of arranging these nodes the way I showed above.

As a final question: is there an easy way to apply `\bfseries` to all *first* node parts? So for `Alpha`, `Beta`, and `Gamma`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the anchors `two east` and `text west` for both the positioning and the arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,%
    mod/.style={%
        draw,%
        rectangle split,rectangle split parts=4,%
        minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2cm}%
]
    \node[mod] (a) {%
        Alpha
        \nodepart{two} betas
        \nodepart{three} foo
        \nodepart{four} bar
    };
    \node[mod,right=of a.two east,anchor=text west] (b) {%
        Beta
        \nodepart{two} gammas
        \nodepart{three} foo
        \nodepart{four} bar
    };
    \node[mod,right=of b.two east,anchor=text west] (c) {%
        Gamma
        \nodepart{two}  deltas
        \nodepart{three} foo
        \nodepart{four} bar
    };
    \draw[->] (a.two east) -- (b.text west);
    \draw[->] (b.two east) -- (c.text west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for making only the first text bold, I am afraid that there is no super simple solution. You can replace all `\nodepart` with `\nodepart[font=\normalfont]` and add `font=\bfseries` to the definition of the nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,%
    mod/.style={%
        draw,%
        font=\bfseries,%
        rectangle split,rectangle split parts=4,%
        minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2cm}%
]
    \node[mod] (a) {%
        Alpha
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{two} betas
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{three} foo
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{four} bar
    };
    \node[mod,right=of a.two east,anchor=one west] (b) {%
        Beta
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{two} gammas
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{three} foo
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{four} bar
    };
    \node[mod,right=of b.two east,anchor=one west] (c) {%
        Gamma
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{two}  deltas
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{three} foo
        \nodepart[font=\normalfont]{four} bar
    };
    \draw[->] (a.two east) -- (b.text west);
    \draw[->] (b.two east) -- (c.text west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That’s fantastic, thank you! May I ask what `anchor=text west` means? I can see that without it, the nodes aren’t properly aligned. Does `text` mean the first node part here?

Comment: @bp99 Yes, precisely. See p. 822 of pgfmanual v3.1.5 for the anchors. (One can use `one west` instead.)